# Dash, data encoding, and Neural Network. How to combine it all for prototyping?

Tags: python, deep-learning, plotly-dash, categorical-data, data-preprocessing

Please help me out how to organize the correct prototype to demonstrate to my business users how python and Neural Networks can solve a business case with category prediction.

I have 2 python files:

1. Data_preprocessing_and_model

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('../some_data.XLSX')
data = data.fillna(0)

y = data['Target']

feature2use = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]  #select only 3 main features 

def data_processing(df, cols):
    XX = df[cols]    
    features = [col for col in data.columns if col in cols]
    X = pd.get_dummies(XX, columns=features)

    return X

X = data_processing (data, feature2use)


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          batch_size=1,
          epochs=2,
          verbose=1
          )
```

2nd file. Dash form as front-end for user interaction

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
        children=[
        html.H1(
                children='Welcome to the predictive service ',
                style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': colors['text']}
        ),
        html.Label('Feature #1', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': colors['text']}),
        dcc.Input(id='F1', value='0', type='text'),

        html.Label('Feature #2', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': colors['text']}),
        dcc.Input(id='F2', value='0', type='text'),

        html.Label('Feature #3', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': colors['text']}),
        dcc.Input(id='F3', value='0', type='text'),

        html.P(),
        html.H1('Prediction:', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': colors['text']}),
        html.H2(id='Class',
        style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': colors['text']}),
        ], style={'columnCount': 1, 'width': '70%', 'display': 'inline-block'})

@app.callback(
        Output(component_id='Class', component_property='children'),
        [
                Input(component_id='F1', component_property='value'),
                Input(component_id='F2', component_property='value'),
                Input(component_id='F3', component_property='value')
        ]
)
def Class_prediction(F1, F2, F3):
        from data_preprocessing_and_model import model, data_processing, feature2use

        a1 = str(F1)
        a2 = str(F2)
        a3 = str(F3)
        
        new_df_raw = pd.DataFrame({
                'A' : a1,
                'B' :a2,
                'C' : a3,
                }, index=[0])
        
        new_df = np.array(new_df).reshape(1,-1)
        test_df = data_processing(new_df, feature2use)
   
        class_pred = model.predict(test_df)
        class_pred_max = np.argmax(class_pred)
        return class_pred_max

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The logic is straight simple too. User input new categorical data and should receive class prediction. My concerns here are:

1. Dummies. Since I deal with categorical initial data, I have to encode it first. But with the **get_dummies** I doubt that I can import the same dictionary from the first file. At the same time, users can input (and they really do) previously unseen for preprocessing function data... Should I use instead of **get_dummies** e.g. **sklearn.preprocessing.LableEncoder** with **.fit_transform** in first file and **.transform** for the new dataset in the second file?
2. Overal architecture for Dash app. When I start the Dash App, the model begins to run again. For now, it doesn`t affect my hardware, but for complex models I assume there should be a more elegant way to use pre-trained models. **model.save_weights** and **model.load_weights**?
3. New unseen data. In case user-inputted new data that is unknown for the model, should I add a function to the Dash App to merge the new data with the initial, to encode it before modeling? Guess it can affect performance as well for huge initial data amounts.

Thank you in advance